# PHP array_search for multi dimensional array and return key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to search for a value in a multi dimensional array (below is only a part of the big array) and get the key for that value but I can't manage it by myself. Here is what I have tried :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => SMEG - 30
            [1] => ALES
            [2] => -
            [3] => -
            [4] => -
            [5] => ALES
            [6] => 44-
            [7] => -
            [8] => FR*S30*E36*1*1
            [9] => FR*S30*E36*1*1
            [10] => US*S30
            [11] => Oui
            [12] => 3376
            [13] => Normale
            [14] => -
        )

    [1] => Array  // <-- wanted key
        (
            [0] => SMEG - 30
            [1] => ALES
            [2] => -
            [3] => Chemin Des Sports
            [4] => -
            [5] => ALES
            [6] => -
            [7] => -
            [8] => FR*S30*E37*2*1  // <-- wanted value
            [9] => FR*S30*E37*2*1
            [10] => FR*S30
            [11] => Oui
            [12] => 33762
            [13] => Normale
            [14] => -
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => SMEG - 30
            [1] => ALES
            [2] => 0
            [3] => Ecole Des Mines
            [4] => -
            [5] => ALES
            [6] => 4-
            [7] => -
            [8] => FR*S30*E38*2*1
            [9] => FR*S30*E38*2*1
            [10] => FR*S30
            [11] => Oui
            [12] => 3376
            [13] => Normale
            [14] => -
        )
)

$key = array_search("FR*S30*E37*2*1", array_column($data, '8'));
var_dump($data[$key]);
```

With this code I can't get the key of desired array. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What do you get exactly? Also note that your code will fail if the keys are not sequential, for example if an element is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to key, you could use `array_filter`

```
$result = array_filter($data, function($item) use ($search) {
    return $item[8] == $search;
})[0];
```

If you need the key, you could modify it like this

```
$key = false;
$result = array_filter($data, function($item, $k) use ($search, &$key) {
    if ($item[8] == $search) {
        $key = $k;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH)[0];
```

To handle cases, where no result is found, you have to skip the `[0]` party and test if `count($result) != 0`

Answer (score 0):

Try this function for recursive searching:

```
function array_search_recursive($needle, array $haystack)
    {
        foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
            $current_key = $key;

            if ($needle === $value or (is_array($value) && array_search_recursive($needle, $value) !== false)) {
                return $current_key;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

$key = array_search_recursive("FR*S30*E37*2*1", $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/764570)

```
<?php
$array=Array
(
    0=>   Array
        (
            0=>   "SMEG - 30",
            1=>   "ALES",
            2=>   "-",
            3=>   "-",
            4=>   "-",
            5=>   "ALES",
            6=>   "44-",
            7=>   "-",
            8=>   "FR*S30*E36*1*1",
            9=>   "FR*S30*E36*1*1",
            10=>   "US*S30",
            11=>   "Oui",
            12=>   "3376",
            13=>   "Normale",
            14=>   "-"
        ),

    1=>   Array
        (
            0=>   "SMEG - 30",
            1=>   "ALES",
            2=>   "-",
            3=>   "Chemin Des Sports",
            4=>   "-",
            5=>   "ALES",
            6=>   "-",
            7=>   "-",
            8=>   "FR*S30*E37*2*1",
            9=>   "FR*S30*E37*2*1",
            10=>   "FR*S30",
            11=>   "Oui",
            12=>   "33762",
            13=>   "Normale",
            14=>   "-",
        ),

    2=>   Array
        (
            0=>   "SMEG - 30",
            1=>   "ALES",
            2=>   "0",
            3=>   "Ecole Des Mines",
            4=>   "-",
            5=>   "ALES",
            6=>   "4-",
            7=>   "-",
            8=>   "FR*S30*E38*2*1",
            9=>   "FR*S30*E38*2*1",
            10=>   "FR*S30",
            11=>   "Oui",
            12=>   "3376",
            13=>   "Normale",
            14=>   "-",
        )
);
$requiredKey=null;
$requiredValue=null;
finder($array,"FR*S30*E37*2*1");
function finder($array,$search)
{
    global $requiredKey,$requiredValue;
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if(in_array($search, $value))
        {
            $requiredKey=$key;
            $requiredValue=$search;
            break;
        }
    }
}
echo $requiredKey;
echo $requiredValue;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!