# PHP multidimensional array: get the key of item that has a certain subkey

Tags: php

Given this array:

```
$columns = [
    ['data' => 'id', 'name' => 'id', 'title' => 'ID', 'class' => 'text-center text-shrink', 'orderable' => false, 'searchable' => false],
    ['data' => 'name', 'name' => 'name', 'title' => 'Nome', 'default' => true],
    ['data' => 'email', 'name' => 'email', 'title' => 'E-mail'],
    ['data' => 'created_at', 'name' => 'created_at', 'title' => 'Creato il', 'class' => 'text-center'],
    ['data' => 'updated_at', 'name' => 'updated_at', 'title' => 'Aggiornato il', 'class' => 'text-center'],
    ['data' => 'action', 'name' => 'action', 'title' => 'Azioni', 'class' => 'text-center text-shrink', 'orderable' => false, 'searchable' => false],
];
```

How do I retrieve the key of the only item that has `'default' => true` (it should be `1` in this case)? I could do it with a loop, but isn't there an easy way for trivial task like this? Please notice that I can also use Laravel helpers

Please notice that this is not a duplicate of a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102221/php-multidimensional-array-searching-find-key-by-specific-value): here I am sure that the `default` subkey exists in only one array item and not in the others, so I can't use `array_column()` and then get the one with a certain value

Thank you

Comment: please state your current attempt. also `array_column()` should help

Comment: loops are usually the most efficient way for this kind of tasks, i always wonder why so many people always prefer less readable and performant solutions..

Comment: There are plenty of solutions in that duplicate that don't involve `array_column`…

Comment: @deceze, the other solutions involve a loop: I stated in my question that I could go with it but I'm looking for a "two lines solution" (if any, of course :-) )

Comment: Fine, more options here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43120997/476, https://stackoverflow.com/a/31590256/476